# App Insights not using RequestTelemetryFilter for health check Controller in Spring Boot app

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a Spring Boot app with a few Controllers I want to track their dependencies (including outbound Http requests). That all works as expected. However, I have one controller for a health check (returning 204) that I do not want telemetry for. All other responses mention custom code components, but according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-filter-telemetry), this should be doable within the AI-Agent.xml config.

```
<BuiltInProcessors>
  <Processor type="RequestTelemetryFilter">
    <Add name="NotNeededResponseCodes" value="204" />
  </Processor>
</BuiltInProcessors>
```

I notice on the classpath that there are two RequestTelemtryFilter instances (one from ai-core and one from ai-web, neither of which get hit when i debug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the Agent (via AI-Agent.xml) is different than configuring custom telemetry (via Applicationinsights.xml). Spring boot + the agent requires the use of a custom Telemetry Processor and pulling into your configuration via @Bean. No additional XML in the AI-Agent is necessary.

```
public class HealthCheckTelemetryFilter implements TelemetryProcessor
{

  public HealthCheckTelemetryFilter()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public boolean process(Telemetry telemetry)
  {
    RequestTelemetry reqTel = (RequestTelemetry) telemetry;

    if(reqTel.getResponseCode().equals(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.toString()))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
  }

}
```

NOTE: dont forget appropriate type check